# Can't install Scrapyd on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, scrapy, scrapyd

i'm trying to install scrapyd service in a EC2 instance to deploy a scrapy project .

**what i have done :**

1- Imported the GPG key used to sign Scrapy packages into APT keyring:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 627220E7
```

2- Created /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list file using the following command:

```
sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list"
```

3- installing scrapyd

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapyd
```

i get the following error :

```
Err:7 http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu precise InRelease
Could not connect to archive.scrapy.org:80 (54.83.53.20), connection timed out
Err:8 http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy InRelease
Unable to connect to archive.scrapy.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'scrapy.listecho' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.scrapy.org:80 (54.83.53.20), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/dists/scrapy/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.scrapy.org:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
enter code here
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Try to go to http://archive.scrapy.org using your web browser...

Comment: i've tried your suggestion , but i got the following error " This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The site your server is trying to download from is not currently online.  There could be any number of possible causes, but what you can reasonably conclude is that the issue is not with your server, the problem is somewhere else.  It isn't something you have the ability to fix.  You'll need to find out (via googling) if this is a transient problem, or a planned change or scheduled maintenance, or if perhaps the instructions have changed and the ones you are following are obsolete (though they don't appear to be).