# Unable to download scrapyd on ec2

Tags: python, scrapy

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapyd

Err:7 http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu precise InRelease
Could not connect to archive.scrapy.org:80 (31.125.20.14), connection timed out
Err:8 http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy InRelease
Unable to connect to archive.scrapy.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'scrapy.listecho' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.scrapy.org:80 (31.125.20.14), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu/dists/scrapy/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.scrapy.org:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
enter code here
```

I installed scrapy without any error, now I want to install scrapyd but it gives this error

I checked [Can't install Scrapyd on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866421/cant-install-scrapyd-on-ec2?rq=1),but no answer was there

Comment: Just so you know, the problem isn't with your callback. Gumtree has incorporated a second layer of security using distilnetworks. I have tried for a bit to find out how to bypass it but I am out of ideas.

Comment: distil detects selenium even if you solve and submit, a new captcha will show with every couple of pages you visit

Comment: you should carefully analyze the requests you send to the website when performing normal navigation and then try to re-create then with selenium

Comment: As I'm sure you know, the point of Captcha is to disallow automation.  If this is your dev environment, then you should turn off Captcha in that environment.  If you don't work for Gumtree and are successful, then that would be a security issue that should be reported to them.